# Какая есть альтернатива ngif в jquerry

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

я только начал изучать jquery, после angular. Собственно, у меня есть пару вопросов. У меня есть две кнопки(вход и знак профиля), которые должны выводиться в зависимости от условия. То есть, если у меня в localStorage что-то есть, то выводить 1 кнопку, если нет, то 2. В angular  я мог сделать вот так:

```html
<div *ngIf="blabla">
  
</div>
```

Есть ли что-то подобное в jquery или нужно делать сниппеты html, который потом подставлять?

2. Допустим, что мне прилетают данные из сервера, который я помещаю в переменную. Чтобы вывести, я так понял, нужно тоже делать сниппет html или по отдельным селекторам вставлять.

Если это так, то не слишком много ли html в js коде будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `jquery` таких конструкций нет.
Но можно скрывать/показывать существующие элементы ДОМ. А так же создавать новые или удалять старые.

> Если это так, то не слишком много ли html в js коде будет?

Смотря сколько кода напишешь...